# Rouge syntax highlighter options on Kramdown fenced code-blocks

Tags: markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown, kramdown, rouge

When setting options for Rouge on fenced code blocks, the option gets ignored and has no effect, the HTML doesn't change:

````
``` html?line_numbers=true
<html></html>
```
````

I am using Jekyll, Kramdown and Rouge on GitHub Pages.

**Is this supported - should it work?**

---

My `_config.yml`:

```
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    default_lang: text
    span:
      default_lang: text
      line_numbers: false
    block:
      default_lang: text
      # line_numbers: false
      # start_line: 1
```

- I've seen [several blog posts](http://mrloh.se/2015/05/bending-markdown-for-jekyll-and-github-pages/#update-march-2016-github-pages-enforcing-kramdown-and-rouge) where it supposedly working.
- Also I am aware I could use `{% highlight %}` tags, but this is **not** an option.
- I have tested several different options, not just `line_numbers`, also with colon instead of an equal sign, space between the language and the option, alot of combinations I could think of. Either they get ignored or break the fenced code blocks.